# Reset document.body after running test React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-testing-library

After each test, I would like to reset the `document.body` since I am adding some classes on `document.body`. I was under the impression that react testing library would reset it after each test, but it seems that it is reusing the `document` since classes added in the previous test are still visible in the next test when using `debug`.

Comment: Have you tried resetting it using the afterAll() method or afterEach()?

Comment: how should i reset it?

Comment: document.body.className = ""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RTL's [cleanup](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#cleanup) function will not clear the HTML element [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) attribute. See [v12.1.5/src/pure.js#L102](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/blob/v12.1.5/src/pure.js#L102) of `cleanup`:

```js
function cleanup() {
  mountedContainers.forEach(cleanupAtContainer)
}

// maybe one day we'll expose this (perhaps even as a utility returned by render).
// but let's wait until someone asks for it.
function cleanupAtContainer(container) {
  act(() => {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(container)
  })
  if (container.parentNode === document.body) {
    document.body.removeChild(container)
  }
  mountedContainers.delete(container)
}
```

It will do three things:

1. Unmount the component rendered inside the [`container`](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/blob/v12.1.5/src/pure.js#L46)(the HTML `div` element by default) HTML element.
2. The `container` HTML element will be removed from `document.body`.
3. Deleted from the [`mountedContainers`](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/blob/v12.1.5/src/pure.js#L28) JS `Set`.

So if you want to reset/restore the `className` at `document.body` element, you need to do it by yourself. The `afterEach()`/`afterAll()` hooks is the right place to do it.

```
afterEach(() => {
  document.body.className = '';
});

test('t-1', () => {
  document.body.className = 'test-1';
  //...
});

test('t-1', () => {
  document.body.className = 'test-2';
  //...
});
```

There is only one `document.body` element created by JSDOM. So don't think RTL will create a `document.body` before running each test case and clean it up after each test when using the `render` function. The `render` function will create a `container`.

Comment: I used `document.body.removeAttribute('class');` instead of `document.body.className = '';`. This is also fine right?

Comment: @illiteratewriter Yes, it’s fine